# Crash after energy cutdown during upgrade from Ubuntu Studio 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: boot, upgrade, unattended-upgrades

Last night I executed upgrade from Ubuntu studio 17.04 to Ubuntu studio 17.10. while doing it, I accidentally unplugged the power source. After rebooting, an advertising told me that upgrade was incomplete and offered to continue it. I choosed to get the upgrade installed, everything seemed to go well, and after ir, I noticed that I couldn't open navigators. Neither Firefox nor Chromium. I was tired, so I didn't try anything else and went to sleep.

Today, I turn the PC on, Ubuntu Studio startup animation is shown, and then I get a black screen. I can see a static text line on the upper left corner, but I can't type anything. So I pressed computer's power button to shut it off. Ubuntu studio animation appears again, it spells something like "unattended upgrade Will be installed in 5s" and stays that way for dime minutes. I (my damned impatience) turn computer off and restart it. The same happens, excepting the power off animation and the advertising about the failed upgrade. Now it just turns on and off like everything's okay, but I can't run the system. I just get that black screen and can't do anything.

Can anyone help? Thanks!